# How do i test multiple test/train splits

Tags: python, matplotlib, train-test-split

I am trying to test several train/test splits when running my lstm model and then display the results like the grapgh below

i.e.

1. train 80 test 20
2. train 70 test 30
3. train 60 test 40
4. train 50 test 50
5. mean

[image]

How best can i do this in python (test several splits and show results)

Comment: What do you mean by a function? You could make a `np` array like `train_sample_arr = np.arange(50,100,10)` and then set `test_sample_arr = 100-train_sample_arr` and then multiply the array elements with the dataset size and sample the corresponding distribution.

Comment: I shouldn’t have said function, I meant what’s the best way to do it. Can you provide a sample code of what you mean please, I don’t quite follow

Comment: just build a dictionary of datasets with the different splits `splits = {cutoff: train_test_split(X, y, test_size=cutoff / 100 for cutoff in (20, 30, 40, 50)}`

Comment: It’s a time series problem so I’m not using train_test_split function. Instead I have: `X_train = X[:160]  ,  X_test  = X[160:],
y_train = y[:160] . y_test  = y[160:]`